# RSPEC test and Ruby Object

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I'm trying to write some code to make an RSPEC test pass for Ruby. But I'm having some trouble even getting the first test to pass. I think if I can have a little help with this, I'll be able to get the rest. But I can post the rest of the tests if that makes it easier to offer advice.

So it's constructing a fahrenheit/celsius converter, but using objects and classes instead of just defining a couple of methods to do the conversions.

The first part looks like this

```
   require "temperature"

describe Temperature do

  describe "can be constructed with an options hash" do
    describe "in degrees fahrenheit" do
      it "at 50 degrees" do
        Temperature.new(:f => 50).in_fahrenheit.should == 50
      end
```

One of the hints in the instructions says that the Temperature object constructer should accept an options hash with either a :celsius or :fahrenheit entry.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this test for the last few weeks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what I have so far trying to get the first test to pass.

class Temperature
  attr_accessor :fahrenheit 
  def initialize options = {}
   @fahrenheit = :f
  end
  def in_fahrenheit({ :f})
   Temperature.new({:f})
  end

end

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete.  Please add the missing 'end' keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Temperature class needs some work.  Why not have a 'scale' attribute that can set the base value of your Temperature object?

Here's a modified version of what you've posted:

```
class Temperature
  attr_accessor :value, :scale
  def initialize(value, options={})
    @value = value
    if options.has_key?(:scale)
      @scale = options[:scale]
    else
      @scale = :c
    end
  end
  def in_fahrenheit()
    if @scale == :c
      ( @value * 9.0/5.0 ) + 32.0 
    else
      @value
    end
  end 
end
```

There's no need to create a new Temperature object when you call #in_fahrenheit.  You can make your current object convert a number (stored in an attribute) into fahrenheit.  You can add the temperature information when you create your object:

```
t1=Temperature.new(68, :scale =>:f)
t2=Temperature.new(0)

2.0.0dev :199 > t1.in_fahrenheit  => 68 
2.0.0dev :200 > t2.in_fahrenheit  => 32.0
```

Comment: Thanks @LazyMonkey, I see where you're going with this. I appreciate the tips, but when i try and run it pass the test I get:

undefined method `*' for {:f=>50}:Hash
     # ./08_temperature_object/temperature.rb:13:in `in_fahrenheit'
     # ./08_temperature_object/temperature_object_spec.rb:27

Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Not clear if you're referring to your original class or my mods.  I'd guess your RSpec test is having trouble with your #in_fahrenheit method, because you define {:f} as a method parameter.  That looks wrong (it's only a symbol inside braces, not a :key => value pair.)  Not sure that's valid Ruby syntax (I can't get it to pass!)  Please post & format your Temperature class.